# What and how to resolve "Failed to create video converter" in LibVlcSharp

Tags: video-processing, libvlc, libvlcsharp

Playing with the example PreviewThumbnailExtractor.Skia of libvlcsharp-samples-windows.sln, and changing the input file with other input files I got the error:
[Error] main:Failed to create video converter. Why is that and how can I resolve it.
I tried to search for this error but found nothing.. I'm working on Windows platform .NET 7

Comment: share full code so we can reproduce locally. That includes video samples

Comment: The code is the LibVlcSharp: PreviewThumbnailExtractor.Skia.  Link to a movie (change in the example) - https://www.dropbox.com/s/m1eea87cmdfsb2l/test_vs.MP4?dl=0